# Why does not using unwrap() result in an error?

Tags: types, rust

Using Rust 1.11.0, I get the error:

`error: no method named read_to_string found for type std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error> in the current scope`

when I'm not using `unwrap()`:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("D:/test/rust/io.txt"); // Error thrown here
    let mut s = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut s);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

This works fine:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("D:/test/rust/io.txt").unwrap();
    let mut s = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut s); // Warning thrown here
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

But it also gives a warning so I have to add another `unwrap()` after `read_to_string()`:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("D:/test/rust/io.txt").unwrap();
    let mut s = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap(); // Notice the 2nd unwrap here
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because [`read_to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) is a method available for types implementing the [`io::Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait. What you are attempting to use it on is a [`Result<fs::File, io::Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html) which does not implement it.

When you call [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) on a `Result<T, E>`, it yields `T` - in this case [`fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.File.html) that does implement `io::Read`.

The warning you are getting when you don't call `unwrap()` on `f.read_to_string(&mut s)` is because the type `Result<T, E>` it returns has an attribute `#[must_use]` which means that it can not just be discarded; you can perform the following ["ignoring" assignment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#ignoring-bindings) to not get the warning:

`let _ = f.read_to_string(&mut s);`

Comment: Additionally, I'd recommend to read the ["Error Handling" chapter of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html) to understand *why* this is the way it is.